# cabal install libClang (Haskell) dont work under minGW

Tags: windows, haskell, clang, cabal

i always get the error:

```
clang library not found
```

i have installed the newest mingw and haskell plattform under win7 also i copied the llvm-2.9-mingw and clang-2.9-mingw32 into the mingw folder

what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be a matter of setting the paths to the library, so the compiler can find it. You may be able to set

```
 LIBRARY_PATH
```

to help gcc find the library.

Comment: do you know how to make this with minGW?

Comment: Enter `export LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/the/library` into a shell before configuring. But also, you need to install the library somewhere.